# How to get "Input" tag value in drop-down options?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form where there is 2 input tags and drop-down option. how can i get value of this 2 input tags whatever user types in "input" tag in the drop-down option.
As user types in the input tag it should be populated into the drop-down option

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="team_a">Team A:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="team_a" name="fname" value=""><br>

  <label for="team_b">Team B:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="team_b" name="lname" value=""><br>

  <!--How can I both input tag mentioned above, in below options-->
  <label for="teams">Choose winning team:</label>
  <select id="teams" name="teams">
    <option class="dropdown-item" value="">Whatever user types in input tag</option>
    <option class="dropdown-item" value="">Whatever user types in input tag</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I have used following code but doesn't work

```
var team_A_value = document.getElementById('team_a').value;
var team_B_value = document.getElementById('team_b').value;
  document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-item')[0].innerHTML = team_A_value;
  document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-item')[1].innerHTML = team_B_value;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `onChange()` trigger on the `<input>`, use a custom param to force the value to a specific `<option>`

```js
function setValue(event, n) {
  
  // User input
  const userinput = event.target.value;
  
  // Get nth typeOf <option>
  const option = document.getElementsByTagName('option')[n];
  
  // Set value
  option.value = option.innerHTML = userinput;
}
```

```html
<label for="team_a">Team A:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="team_a" onchange="setValue(event, 0)" name="fname" value=""><br>

  <label for="team_b">Team B:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="team_b" onchange="setValue(event, 1)" name="lname" value=""><br>

  <label for="teams">Choose winning team:</label>
  <select id="teams" name="teams">
    <option class="dropdown-item" value="">Whatever user types in input tag</option>
    <option class="dropdown-item" value="">Whatever user types in input tag</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
```